# search parameter passed to include

Tags: templating, include, params

I have a template where I would like to pass a search parameter to a craft.entries.section in an included template. The current main template has this:

```
{% include "_includes/testimonial" with
  { type: "agency" } 
  %}
```

Then in the include I have this code where **entry.clientsOrAgency** is a dropdown field and I want it to only show results of the "type" passed in the parent template.

```
{# get one random testimonial entry #}
{% set testimonial = craft.entries.section('testimonials').search(entry.clientsOrAgency,type).order('RAND()').limit(1) %}

{% for quotes in testimonial %}
<div class="testimonial">

  {# matrix field is 'testimonial' - find different quote types #}
  {% for quote in quotes.testimonial %}
    more code here
  {% endfor %} {# quotes.testimonial #}

</div><!--testimonial-->
{% endfor %}{# quote in testimonial #}
```

The above code results in a template error **Undefined index: query**

Not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off – the `search()` parameter doesn't accept multiple parameters, only a [search query](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) (e.g. `.search('body:foobar')`) or an object containing the search query plus [search term options](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultSearchTermOptions). In your case, you're actually passing an object (`.search(entry.clientsOrAgency)`), in which case Craft will look for a `query` parameter on that object (the second parameter is just ignored). Hence your error.

That being said, here's what you probably want:

```
{% set testimonial = craft.entries.section('testimonials').search('clientsOrAgency:'~type).order('RAND()').limit(1) %}
```

The above will search for entries in the `testimonials` section, which has the value equal to `type` in each `clientsOrAgency` field.

However – unless you need (which can be enabled [as a default](https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) for all searching in Craft, or per-search using search term options mentioned above) for the `clientsOrAgency` field, I don't actually think using `search()` is the appropriate approach here. The following would be easier and probably more performant:

```
{% set testimonial = craft.entries.section('testimonials').clientsOrAgency(type).order('RAND()').limit(1) %}
```

Also, you should probably add `.first()` to your `craft.entries` query, in order to only pull a single entry:

```
{% set testimonial = craft.entries.section('testimonials').clientsOrAgency(type).order('RAND()').limit(1).first() %}

{% if testimonial %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Used the second code block - wasn't aware that you could search a field in that way.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, you can even do more advanced stuff like for example `.clientsOrAgency(type~'*')`, to search for `clientsOrAgency` values _starting with_ `type`.